# Upgrade OS from Windows 2012 R2 to Windows 2016 - SDL web 8 Any Impact

Tags: web8

One of our client they are planning to upgrade Tridion servers from Windows 2012 R2 to Windows 2016,

SDL version SDL Web 8.1.0

Please let us know what will be the impact and can you share documentation that will be great.

Answer (score 4):

SDL Web 8.1.0 does not support Windows 2016, see https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-2B8A33B1-33D6-422B-8281-F3087DC0A745&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-3EB06979-15CD-4972-9262-AB049C53A1FF.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2B8A33B1-33D6-422B-8281-F3087DC0A745. You would need to upgrade to SDL Web 8.5.